# python subprocess.call error when pipe to file

Tags: python, subprocess, error-code

I am getting an usual error in python 3.4, when I'm calling a command, say `net view` in the form of: `subprocess.call("net view")` returns `error code 0` (i.e. successful)

But when I do `subprocess.call("net view > targets.txt")` it returns `error code 1` (unsuccessful).

Why does this error appear in python and is there a way to pipe output to file in a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to redirect `stdout` to a file object:

```
from subprocess import check_call
with open("targets.txt","w" ) as f:
    check_call(["net", "view"], stdout=f)
```

`check_call` will raise an error for `any non-zero` exit status.

Comment: got it, nicely done!

Comment: glas@DonD, no worries,  glad it helped

Comment: @DonD: the reason the error occurs is because `>` is a shell redirection operator. `subprocess` does not spaw a shell unless you ask it explicitly. This answer shows the correct way to redirect child process stdout to a file (without using a shell).